# How to track disk writes on a partition by programs in background?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, tracking

Crystal Disk Info tells me there have been over 10TB of writes to my 240GB SSD. This seems strange so I would like to see which programs account to what part of it in  order to reduce the wear.
What I am looking for is an application that would start with Windows and track how much data cumulatively each program writes to partition C:.

Answer (score 1):

Windows' Resource Monitor can show you this information.

Your high disk writes are most likely coming from virtual memory. If you have the RAM and are concerned for the durability of your SSD, you may want to consider moving your page file to another disk. You can do this on Windows in System Properties. In the Advanced tab click on Settings under the Performance section. On the Advanced tab click on Change in the Virtual Memory section. Moving the page file to a HDD may reduce your performance if you don't have enough RAM to keep your pages loaded.

Comment: The resource monitor only provides momentary information, not a summary, and I have page file turned off.